# Disable possibility to paste floating characters to Input number field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, input, ecmascript-6

I have an issue, when trying to disable paste floating number for `<input type='number' />`. I disable `+ - e E .` `onKeyDown` but how to disable it on `onPaste`? For now I can only use `e.preventDefault()` for `onPatste` to disable at whole. How to disable only `+ - e E .`

```
  <CutomInputField
     required
     type='number'
     inputProps={{
       min: '1',
       max: '100',
       autoComplete: 'off',
     }}
     onKeyDown={e =>preventFloatingPointNumber(e)}
     onPaste={e => {
       e.preventDefault()
       // preventFloatingPointNumber(e) //does not work such way
              }
            }
    />

// 'left arrow', 'up arrow', 'right arrow', 'down arrow',
const arrowsKeyCodes = [37, 38, 39, 40];
// 'numpad 0', 'numpad 1',  'numpad 2', 'numpad 3', 'numpad 4', 'numpad 5', 
'numpad 6', 'numpad 7', 'numpad 8', 'numpad 9'
const numPadNumberKeyCodes = [96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105];

const preventFloatingPointNumber = e => {
// allow only [0-9] number, numpad number, arrow,  BackSpace, Tab
if ((e.keyCode < 48 && !arrowsKeyCodes.includes(e.keyCode) || e.keyCode > 57 &&
    !numPadNumberKeyCodes.includes(e.keyCode)) &&
    !(e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 9))
    e.preventDefault()
```

Comment: Why not run a convert a floating point to an integer in `onPaste` ?

Comment: onPaste how you get a value you paste on input field number?

Comment: @PalaniichukDmytro you can use `e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')`

Comment: clipboardData always `null` ethier I use `ctrl + v` or right click moust paste option

Comment: `const pastedData = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
                                        if (isNaN(pastedData))
                                            e.preventDefault()` -works for me thanks